# How to force Alfresco Share use only one language, independent from browsers locale?

Tags: browser, share, alfresco

It's easy to found solution for Alfresco Exlplorer, but which way is proper for Alfresco Share to use only one specific language, independent from web-browser's locale settings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on how you have deployed Alfresco, but assuming that you are working in a production environment, where it is standard practice to place a HTTP proxy/load balancer between your clients and the Alfresco server, you have some potential options.

Share responds to the `Accept-Language` header that is sent by the web browser, so in order to prevent it from switching the language based on this, you could configure your proxy to drop the `Accept-Language` header from incoming client requests.

For example, using Apache you could use `mody_proxy` together with `mod_headers` in a configuration such as

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
RequestHeader unset Accept-Language
```

The first two lines will proxy requests from Apache (most likely running on port 80) to the Tomcat instance hosting Alfresco on port 8080, while the third line will remove the `Accept-Language` header.

Share will then default to the locale of the Java process in which Alfresco is running, so you should make sure that this is set to US English (`en-US`).

Answer (score 6):

Share is based on `Spring Surf` which is on top of `Spring MVC`. By default, the build-in `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver` is used. To override it just define a bean that extends `org.springframework.extensions.surf.mvc.LocaleResolver` as above:

Add bean declaration to any config file imported by `slingshot-application-context.xml`

```
<!-- Override Locale Resolver -->
<bean id="localeResolver" class="mypackage.CustomLocaleResolver" />
```

Add the new LocaleResolver implementation class

```
    package mypackage;

    import java.util.Locale;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import org.springframework.extensions.surf.mvc.LocaleResolver;
    import org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.I18NUtil;

    public class CustomLocaleResolver extends LocaleResolver {

    public Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Locale locale = Locale.FRENCH;
        I18NUtil.setLocale(locale);

        return locale;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could check The `MTAuthenticationFilter.java`

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException
{
    if (req instanceof HttpServletRequest)
    {
        requestHolder.set((HttpServletRequest)req);

        /*if (((HttpServletRequest) req).getHeader(ACCEPT_LANGUAGE_HEADER) == null)
        {
            req = new SlingshotServletRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) req);
            ((SlingshotServletRequestWrapper) req).addHeader(ACCEPT_LANGUAGE_HEADER, "en_US");
        }*/

        //locale will be always 'french' (fr)
        req = new SlingshotServletRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) req);
        ((SlingshotServletRequestWrapper) req).addHeader(ACCEPT_LANGUAGE_HEADER, "fr");
    }
    try
    {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
    finally
    {
        requestHolder.remove();
    }
}
```

This filter checks for `Accept-language` header otherwise english will be set.
But why not overriding it,then we can put the locale that we want for the entire share application.

This solution works for me like a charm. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way it to remove all the the other *.properties files.

Share doesn't look like Explorer to the web-client-config.xml file.

So a script like `find . -name *_<language>.properties -exec rm -rf {} \;`